# Find pdf of sum of n indp exp RVs w/o using MGFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

From Williams' Probability w/ Martingales:

[image]

---

Re $E[f(S_n)]$, how do I obtain $f_{S_n}(s)$? It seems that

$$f_{S_n}(s) = \frac{s^{n-1} e^{-\lambda s} \lambda^n}{(n-1)!}$$

I tried computing $M_{S_n}(t) = (\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t})^n$ for $t < \lambda$ and then compared it to the mgf of a gamma function: $(1-t\theta)^{-k}$ for $t < \frac{1}{\theta}$ by letting $\lambda = \frac{1}{\theta}$ and $k = n$ and that seems to work, but is there a way to do it from using only CDFs? I was thinking:

$$F_{S_n}(s) = P(S_n \le s)$$

$$ = P(X_1 + ... + X_n \le s)$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{a_1} \int_{0}^{a_2} \cdots \int_{0}^{a_n} \lambda^n e^{-\lambda(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)} dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n$$

where $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n = s$

$$ = \int_{0}^{a_1} \int_{0}^{a_2} \cdots \int_{0}^{a_n} \lambda^n e^{-\lambda(s_n)} dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n$$

or something like that and then differentiate $F_{S_n}(s)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for moment generating functions or Laplace transforms; this follows from a simple induction argument.

Let $X_k\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Then $X_1$ has density $$ f_{S_1}(t) = f_{X_1}(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t) = \frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t).$$

Now, assuming that $S_n$ has density

$$f_{S_n}(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t) = \frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t)$$

for a positive integer $n$ and since we have $S_{n+1}=S_n+X_{n+1}$, by [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) the density of $S_{n+1}$ is,
\begin{align}
f_{S_{n+1}}(t) &= (f_{S_n}\star f_{X_1})(t)\\
&= \int_\mathbb R f_{S_n}(\tau)f_{X_1}(t-\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \int_\mathbb R \frac{(\lambda \tau)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda \tau}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(\tau)\lambda e^{-\lambda(t-\tau)}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t-\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t)\int_0^t \tau^{n-1}\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Math1000. I'm going to review convolutions and then check this later

Comment: Math1000, what happened to the indicator functions in the penultimate line, and how did there come to be an indicator function at the end?

Comment: The indicator functions were used explicitly in the convolution equation to determine the limits of integration (in this case, $0<\tau\infty$). Of course, since both $S_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are both concentrated on $(0,\infty)$, this is being a bit more pedantic. than needed.

Comment: I think I'll just omit indicator functions. Thanks :P

Comment: Oops, meant $0<\tau<\infty$ there. Anyway, indicator functions are a more compact way of expressing piecewise functions. I highly recommend you become familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks. How about I state before hand t > 0?

Comment: That works too.