# How to show that if two random variables $X,Y$ have MGFs that exist, and that each of the moments are the same, they have the same distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have that $X,Y$ have moment generating functions that exist, and that the moments are the same, how can I show that they have the same distribution? Specifically, I am assuming that $E(X^n) = E(Y^n)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I've tried this with the standard approach but can't quite get it. I believe as long as I can manipulate that equation into the moment generating form for both $X,Y$, then I can get it. However, trying to take the exponential of both sides leaves me with: $e^{E(X^n)} = e^{E(Y^n)}$, which I cannot take the expectation to the outside. Does anyone have any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the [inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulas) for characteristic functions.

Comment: @MarcusM Cool. Is that like a generalisation of [inverting laplace transforms](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515989/find-pdf-of-sum-of-n-indp-exp-rvs-w-o-using-mgfs) ?